# How can I deal with App launches slowly on Lollipop at first launch?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using Android Studio to develop my app.

While running app by Android Studio, both Android 4.x and 5.x launch the app quickly.

But after I using some domestic reinforce service to add shell, app launches take 3 seconds in Android 5.x while 1 second in Android 4.x.

I just do not know what the cause is... Why does it launch so slowly in Android 5.x?

Here is my build.gradle, and thank you for your tips if you know.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myatejx.sakernote'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 72
        versionName '0.7.2'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            shrinkResources true
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile project(':SwipeActionAdapter')
    compile project(':SystemBarTint')
    compile project(':DragSortListView')
    compile project(':MaterialSetting')
}
```

Comment: I think gridle file is fine, but post your main activity's code. If there is any issue with that.

Comment: But the demo "Hello World" also launches slowly in Android 5.x after adding shell